# Java generics, coming from C++ templates

Tags: java, generics

I find the following code remarkable in Java:

```
    ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println(l1.getClass() == l2.getClass()); // true
    System.out.println(l2.getClass().isAssignableFrom(l1.getClass())); // true too
    //ArrayList<Integer> l3 = l1; // won't compile though
```

I don't quite understand the details of "isAssignableFrom". Of course, I want the compiler to stop l3 = l2, but it seems to be in contradiction to the previous line? (I'm sure there are subtle points here, that's what I'm after :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of the `<Blah>` information is stripped away after compile time. As far as the bytecode is concerned, they're all the same class.

When it comes to during the compile, they're checked for consistency and compatibility.

So when it does the check of `l2.getClass().isAssignableFrom(l1.getClass())` it's saying `is ArrayList assignable from ArrayList?` and the answer is yes. But because during the compile it still has type information, it's not allowed.

Comment: Specifically, this is called *type erasure*. The Java tutorial on generics is pretty good at explaining the pitfalls of Java generics: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Yeah, well, it feels a bit contradictory, because something is true at runtime but not at compile time, or, it's assignable, but you can't assign. It doesn't feel quite right :-)

Comment: @Frank I suppose the mentality relying on runtime correctness would be poor design; instead we should be designing our code such that errors are caught at compile time. That's not to say we succeed all the time :)

Comment: Sure, I agree with that. My main issue is that the class are equal and not equal at the same time. As for doing more stuff at compile time, I like to move as much of the runtime to compile time as I can, in C++ (no chance of being able to do that in Java).

Comment: You can't do much of it in Java because, honestly, Java can do it better than we can with the JIT. And to be fair, they're not both equal and not equal at the same time, but rather they're equal at one time and not equal at another.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by Java's (rather sloppy) implementation of generics, namely [Type Erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Basically the compiler erases type information (eg: `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayList<Integer>` both become `ArrayList`) and adds casts where necessary. At runtime there's no type distinction between `l1` and `l2`, but the compiler won't let you do the assignment - because *it* knows the types are different.

Answer (score 0):

This is because [erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) of generics.

Answer (score 0):

**isAssignableFrom()  is testing if the classes are identical, or if the second one is a superclass or superinterface of the first.**

As the other answers have stated, the generics are removed during compile time, so they have no effect on the output of that method. Only the base classes mater.

Reference: [`Class.isAssignableFrom()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: That's back to front. It is the first class that is tested for being a superclass or superinterface of the 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted could have been served by a `getType()` method, and `l1.getType()` should return `ArrayList<String>`, and `l2.getType()` should return `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Unfortunately, Java doesn't have `getType()` on Object. `getClass()` return `ArrayList` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since you found out that `l1.getClass() == l2.getClass()` is true, then `l2.getClass().isAssignableFrom(l1.getClass())` should be obvious (`x.isAssignableFrom(x)` should always be true, no?). Your real question is why `l1.getClass() == l2.getClass()` is true, which is due to erasure. There is just one class at runtime.